# PHP returns whyever HTML tags

Tags: php, html, xmlhttprequest

Okay, i have this php code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      $q = intval($_GET['q']);
      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testDB');
      if(!$con){
        die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error($con));
      }

      mysqli_select_db($con, "testDB");
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `aTable`;";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      echo $row[$q];
      mysqli_close($con);
      exit();
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I call this script by HTML:

```
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var Response = this.responseText;
            console.log(Response);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "script.php?q=1", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Whyever, the console logs

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    -3, -1, -2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, -1, -3, -1
```

I don't know why, but the it returns these HTML tags, which I not want (only the values from -3 to -1 [with commas])

How can I remove the (unclosed) HTML tags?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Remove the HTML tags from your file. Of course.

Comment: Open your PHP file in a text editor.  Remove what you don't want.  Save the file.  (Note: The tags are "unclosed" because you call `exit()` which terminates the script before you close the tags.)

Comment: Really question like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `script.php` via ajax the response will contain all html tags in your file, make sure to remove them all. Also You may want to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to send php objects as strings to the client, here is an example:

**script.php**

```
<?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testDB');
    if(!$con){
        die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con, "testDB");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `aTable`;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo json_encode($row[$q], true);
    mysqli_close($con);
    exit();
```

Hope this helps